# cell value msgbox prints the wrong value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I have a simple spreadsheet with a timestamp and name columns.
I was trying to make a macro to subdivide the column timestamp into two other's columns instead (Date and Time in different columns). However when trying to debug the cell value on the Timestamp column with Browser.msgbox it will show correctly if cell value still has Date + time on it but it will show the wrong value if cell has only the time ... Any idea why that happen

[image: Print screen of the sheet results]

This is the code i have a , very simple macro

```
function removedate() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var timeStamp = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().getValue();
  Browser.msgBox(timeStamp);
}
```

Comment: It seems that a way around this is change the cell format to text. Changing it to text it will work properly but it's weird to be in that way. If someone could explain why it would be nice

Answer (score 0):

If you type in time (such as "15:20") in one cell and full date-time with the same time into another cell, then you will have **different values** in both cells, as shown in msgbox exactly. If you want **the same value** in both cells and different display values, you should use different [format options](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/56470?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en). If you want to convert full date-time to time-only value, you can use [TIMEVALUE function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267350). But if you try to read converted value as a full date-time, you will get some wrong (no sence) result.

As for your initial task "Date and Time in different columns", you have a direct solution in using DATEVALUE and TIMEVALUE functions and proper format options:

[image]